# the correct order Acronyms

Tags: acronyms, sorting, acro

[image]

Hey how can I get the correct order of the Acronyms in the same order in the Dokument `\input{Acronyms}`.
Obviously he does automatic sorting

[image]

Comment: I would recommend spending some more time to explain your problem including providing a better example. I do not see an actual question in your question. See the comments to your previous question.

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default `acro` always did and still does order the list of acronyms. If you don't want that do

```
\acsetup{sort=false}
```

in version 2.x which is what you are using or

```
\acsetup{list/sort=false}
```

in version 3.x.

Comment: Great thanks! it's working with \acsetup{sort=false}

Comment: @Hussein you're welcome